# MapsV2 how to fake a click of the myLocation button

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

In MapsV2, I would like to programmatically perform a click of the myLocation button that appears on the top right of the map.

In previous versions of MapsV2, I could get a handle on the button by traversing the view hierarchy and then say myButton.performClick() (and also if I wanted could reposition the button on the map). But in the latest release this has stopped working so I think Google have deliberately disabled this potential.

How else can I center the map on the current location from code, as if the user had pressed the button?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just use

```
map.getMyLocation()
```

which returns you the location of the blue dot then just change the camera to that location

```
CameraPosition position = new CameraPosition.Builder()
   .target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()))
   .zoom(zoom).build();

map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(position));
```

there is also a `OnMyLocationButtonClickListener` if you want to listen for the my location button click

Comment: Sadly this method is now deprecated, see https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#getMyLocation%28%29 and https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/location